telebot Http 400: bad request
Сделал бота для скачивания видео с ютуба с помощью pytube, но по какой-то причине выдает ошибку Http 400 bad request, может это связано как-то с размером файла?
import telebot
from pytube import YouTube
import os

API_TOKEN = 'Тут был мой токен'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "отправь мне ссылку на видео в ютубе и я скачаю его в качестве 720р!")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def download_video(message):
    url = message.text
    try:
        yt = YouTube(url)
        stream = yt.streams.filter(res="720p", file_extension="mp4").first()
        
        if stream:
            video_path = stream.download()
            with open(video_path, 'rb') as video:
                bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video)

            os.remove(video_path)
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, "не удалось найти видео в качестве 720р")
    
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, f"ошибка: {e}")

bot.polling()


Так этот pytube несколько лет не обновлялся. А ютуб всё время меняет форматы. yt_dlp вроде актуальная штука, свежая.

Все будет хорошо если поставить bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True)Потому что он продолжает работу бота не смотря на сетевые или какие либо ошибки
